# Error Parsing XML; not well formed (invalid token) in xml file

Tags: android, xml, compiler-errors

I have this error :
Error:(2) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\AndroidSdk\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

< menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_map"
    android:title="@string/action_map"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Try removing the space between `<` and `menu`..., it should be `<menu...`

Comment: Yeah, the space between < and menu breaks the XML. Removing the space makes the XML well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_map"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Try removing space between **<** menu **.** Tested should work.